# Autodesk Forge WalkThrough ERROR: The connection was reset The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am running the WalkThrough example and having great successes just starting out. I am having an issue where Autodesk ReCap Photo (a few versions ago) created an .RCM and .OBJ files. I realize that RCM files are not supported; however the OBJ files should be and these files are the only ones I currently have that completing the translation (or so that is what I am thinking as I get no actual error in the console returned). I instead get a page 'The connection was reset. The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.'... The obj file is only 239mb but I have others much smaller and they give same results. This above message is returned after about 5 mins have elapsed. This timeout is consistent regardless of the actual file size?

I look in the tmp folder and the file was copied and file sizes match exactly. So I am thinking there is something afoul with OBJ files being translated? I have a monster RVT file that while it takes almost 3 minutes returns in the viewer no issues.

Any thoughts as to how I can debug this as I stated the last lines reported in the console are the bucketKey and file location being I assumed sent to the server.

TIA!

Cheers!
Rick...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the timeouts happened when the OBJ files were being uploaded? If so try break larger files down and upload them in chunks using the [resumable endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-resumable-PUT) otherwise our service would time you out after a period of time regardless of the actual size of the file - you may use the [node.js command line tools](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-cli-utils)  to accomplish this w/o bothering to implement your own chunked uploading.

Once the translation job is called our service should return immediately reporting whether the job is created successfully or now - note this response is solely about job creation and not the actual conversion so you'd need to query [GET :urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET) to check on its progress. Let me know if you got timed out while calling the jobs or querying their progress.

Also see [this tutorial here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer/) explaining everything.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. So I am having issue trying to retrieve the session-id value for the call? I searched for session ID on Forge site and here as well and no results were found? Can you assist here?

Comment: If you are after the session id value for resumable upload then it's an arbitrary value - you can put in any value you'd like to identify and keep alive an upload session and retrieve its status by calling [buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName/status/:sessionId](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-status-:sessionId-GET/)